# Java: Is the index value for an unseen element standardized?

Tags: java, sequence, standards

Returning `-1` as a pseudo-index value for unseen/"not-found" [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) elements is quite common across programming languages. However, **is `-1` truly "standardized" in Java as an index value meaning "not in this sequence"?**— I can't find any mention of this in e.g. [the Java language specification for SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html), but that explicitly defines the language itself and has very little mention of [the Java core class libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: [`List.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) clearly states: *or -1 if this list does not contain the element* so implementation are required to do that. For other types of "search" methods, you need to refer to their own documentation: they could very well throw an exception instead of returning -1.

Comment: To answer your question "is it possible that the API specification ..." the answer is Yes. It it possible.

Comment: that's a coding convention. It's not standardized, it just became common use and now everyone conforms to it, because it's a convention and using anything else would only confuse every one. It's not only in java, but pretty much any programming-language. So no, it's not standardized AFAIK, but there's no need to standardize this officially anyways. The convention is strong enough.

Comment: There is at least one method that can return a value different to `-1` for *"item not found"*: see [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) . The behaviour is defined by the contract of the method in question and you have to look it up in the documentation to be really sure...

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the info. If you turn that into an answer, I'll try to accept it before this gets closed.